# How to not get overcharged for disks?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

My disks are configured for 40 GiB and 300 GiB, yet Azure is over-charging me for 128 GiB (E10) and 512 GiB (S20).

[image: Over-charge]

Pricing is here https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/managed-disks/

I'm fine getting charged for mounted space in Linux that's free space.  Yet, getting automatic assignment of larger disks and getting charged for space that I can't potentially use seem not fair.

I'd like to consolidate everything on a single E15 disk (256 GiB). Yet, when configuring disk, how to avoid getting much larger disks than I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be getting charged for 64gb disks. breakdowns are:

```
32, 64, 128, 256, 512, etc
```

disk size is rounded up, so if you have 33 gib disk, you are being billed for 64 gib, and so on.

Reference:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disks-types

Comment: Thanks! Yet, it seems I got one size larger for ssd

Comment: Specifically 40 GiB would have fit under 64 (yet I got 128). The 300 GiB one makes sense.

Comment: 64 and 124 have different IOPS, that’s probably why I got it. Thanks!